# how to prevent wordpress custom theme hacking

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a problem that every some days my theme has changed and add one file upload form.In wordpress editor i found some hacking code

so how to increase my security in wordpress theme

Comment: Don't use spyware-infected computers to work on your site, don't use Filezilla, update Wordpress regularly. This is off-topic for SO anyway.

Comment: Have you read http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked and http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to keep your website updated with latest version of Wordpress and your plugins as well in order to not leaving yourself open to attacks.If your username is "admin" and your password isn"t strong enough, your site is defenceless to a malicous attack. Never use admin as your user name. I recommend you to install "wordfence security" plugin for your website"s security.